# 'arrival date' button does not react when using selenium .click()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am doing a selenium exercise on commercial website "https://www.landal.com/parks/orveltermarke/prices-and-availability#filter:eyJhIjoiMDItMDctMjAyMSIsImFhIjowLCJhYiI6MCwibiI6Mywic3QiOjkyNCwicyI6IjMifQ==". The goal to a. open website->b. close privacy cookie-> c. open the arrival date drop down list-> d. click 1st available arrival date. The a. ~ c. steps work pretty well except step d.: I have tried to find the button by Xpath:

**input for step 3**

*list=webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rnd19"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody//button')

list[0].click

**below output of 'print(list)' shows list contains 9 available arrival dates but the web seem not interact with 'list[0].click'. Why not? many thanks!**

[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="0216bfa1-81fd-4f1a-9198-04a1bfc32f0d")>,

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="8554cda1-57d8-41e5-b4fc-5aab884d2cb5")>,

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="5c5884a8-ac4b-484b-8139-5a8546c7b201")>,

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="0b08b6e6-3a0e-4857-9c4e-f4ab0841b343")>,

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="69a8af48-e772-45f7-828a-15fa7c689202")>,

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="78dda943-6b38-46cd-a63e-1c5ae4c52da2")>,

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="94e3dfd4-7284-405e-b836-3b1c643a88e7")>,

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="37d00624-766e-4ce1-8880-9a5b49a15ed7")>,

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e86a30e1f11647288022ecc6fbd030d", element="c144c8bf-5535-46b6-91d4-3ae0dca34b18")>]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take smaller steps, I suppose. Check out this code chunk. It works well for **Jul 16, 2021**.

```
# Accepting the cookies
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="consentRelevant"]').click()
time.sleep(5)

# Arrival date calendar dropdown
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rnd17"]/div/div[1]')[0].click()
time.sleep(3)

# Loop through 'tr[i]' (to select the week) and 'td[j]' (to select the day from that week)
# The indexing for both tr[i] and td[j] starts from 1
li = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rnd19"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[6]/button')
time.sleep(2)
li[0].click()
```

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I try the same approach: it works at the first then I tried to loop over each button, it does not work anymore.  reporting:                                                                                        "<bound method WebElement.click of <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2202dc1318a8e95a567d2a49e5ca6fa5", element="62f59bbe-b494-4166-b7fb-2a48addd5f0a")>>"

Comment: would it be possible that web has selenium detector and blocked selenium actions? weird that I can manually click.